# Return only field in query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have the following query which relates to my WP site.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp2d_postmeta` WHERE `post_id` = 7383 and `meta_key` = 'product_guidelines'
```

Which returns the following data:

[image: Query Results]

How can I only return the metal_value field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to select only that column. Not all columns (*):

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp2d_postmeta WHERE post_id = 7383 and meta_key = 'product_guidelines'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was added to my site [link](http://www.izami.co.za) Working perfectly now.